# Android Calendar.getInstance() does not get today after midnight

Tags: android, android-calendar

I have the following code:

```
Calendar nextSchedule = Calendar.getInstance();
nextSchedule.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
nextSchedule.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
nextSchedule.set(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
nextSchedule.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
nextSchedule.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

long diff = nextSchedule.getTimeInMillis() - cal.getTimeInMillis();
long seconds = diff / 1000;
long minutes = seconds / 60;
long hours = minutes / 60;
```

As expected, around 11am it gave me 13/12hours but when doing the following in a widget:

```
Calendar nextSchedule = Calendar.getInstance();
nextSchedule.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
nextSchedule.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
nextSchedule.set(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
nextSchedule.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
nextSchedule.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextSchedule.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Around 1:30am, it was still not updated. Only somewhen between 2am and 9am (I was asleep) it got updated.

A similar strange thing happens elsewhere. I have a calendar view (applandeo) with the following code: `cvCalendar.setOnDayClickListener(eventDay -> showDateItems(eventDay,lvCalendar));`

```
private void showDateItems(EventDay eventDay, ListView lvCalendar) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(eventDay.getCalendar().get(Calendar.YEAR),eventDay.getCalendar().get(Calendar.MONTH),eventDay.getCalendar().get(Calendar.DATE));
    cal2.set(eventDay.getCalendar().get(Calendar.YEAR),eventDay.getCalendar().get(Calendar.MONTH),1);
    cal2.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    String line;
    for (ItemsHistoryItem item: Utils.getInstance().itemsHistory) {
        if (item.getxDay() < Utils.getInstance().calenderToEpoch(cal2) && item.getyDay() < Utils.getInstance().calenderToEpoch(cal2)) break;
        if (item.getxDay() != Utils.getInstance().calenderToEpoch(cal) && item.getyDay() != Utils.getInstance().calenderToEpoch(cal)) continue;
        line = item.getItemId() + ": $" + item.getAmount();
        if (item.getxDay() == Utils.getInstance().calenderToEpoch(cal))
            line += " (x day)";
        else
            line += " (y day)";
        items.add(line);
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> lcAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(requireActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    lvCalendar.setAdapter(lcAdapter);
}

long calenderToEpoch(Calendar cal2) {
    return TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(cal2.getTimeInMillis());
}
```

Basically, the above code scans dates of items and when the user select a certain date, he gets a list of items which dates (x and y) are of that date. When doing so during the day, it works. When doing so in 1:30am (for example), it shifts one day ahead so if the user clicks on 12-oct, he gets the items of 11-oct. Somwhen between 2am and 9am it "shifts" back and works as expected.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the default timezone for Calendar.getInstance() in my case was GMT+3 so at 3am the items were shown for their dates and the widget was updated. to fix it, I simply did the following:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion for using alarmmanager properly if you want it to fire exactly at the time you want else it does not fire on time when device is in deep sleep mode and gets delayed:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        // use setAlarmClock function of AlarmManager
        // but this function will show an alarm icon on statusbar
        // if you dont want to show that icon you can use
        // setExactAndAllowWhileIdle function but that will not be 
        // perfectly exact
    }
    else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        // use setExact function of AlarmManager
    }
    else {
        // use set function of AlarmManager
    }
```

Comment: The app is for Marshmallow (6) and up, I understand that setExact is the right way for this. The other issue, that seems similar, makes it look as if the problem is that the app doesn't recognize it's a new day. btw, at 1:30am the phone was "awake", I used it to check the problem and saw it happening. Nevertheless, it looks like the "day pass" was when the phone was idle as I was asleep :)